# How to sum set of string values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a Time column in a table datatype is string  such as

```
0:00:00
1:43:39
2:12:07
0:44:28
0:59:32
```

it is stands like `HH:mm:ss`

i want to add these values . please suggest me to get a solution

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why is it string/varchar and not [`time`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243(v=sql.100).aspx)?

Comment: because of front end restriction.

Comment: store date and time appropriately, not as as strings.

Answer (score 2):

Why is it string/varchar and not [`time`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243(v=sql.100).aspx)? However, you can cast it to `Time`:

```
SELECT  SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', CAST([Time] As Time))) As TimeSumInMinutes
FROM dbo.TableName
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d44e8/4/0)</kbd>